# When should you use node's http over http2?

Tags: node.js, http, networking, https, http2

In which cases should you use the `http` module in node over the `http2` module? The majority of people and libraries seem to still be using the `http` module, even though connections using HTTP/2 are faster and most websites have already switched to it. What's the reason for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `http2` is able to stream web sockets by default

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/2 enables full request and response multiplexing. In practice, this means a connection made to a web server from your browser can be used to send multiple requests and receive multiple responses. This gets rid of a lot of the additional time that it takes to establish a new connection for each request.

```
    /*
     * Example HTTP2 Server
     * Opening a full-duplex (stream) channel on port 6000
     *
     */
    
    // Dependencies
    var http2 = require('http2');
    
    // Init the server
    var server = http2.createServer();
    
    // On a stream, send back hello world html
    server.on('stream', function (stream, headers) {
      stream.respond({
        ':status': 200,
        'content-type': 'text/html',
      });
      stream.end('<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>');
    });
    
    // Listen on 6000
    server.listen(6000);

/*
 * Example HTTP2 client
 * Connects to port 6000 and logs the response
 *
 */

// Dependencies
var http2 = require('http2');

// Create client
var client = http2.connect('http://localhost:6000');

// Create a request
var req = client.request({
  ':path': '/'
});

// When message is received, add the pieces of it together until you reach the end
var str = '';
req.on('data',function(chunk){
  str += chunk;
});

// When a message ends, log it out
req.on('end', function(){
  console.log(str);
});

// End the request
req.end();
```